# is it possible to create new virtual environment in Julia using environment file (like .yml)?

Tags: julia, virtualenv

is there a way to setup a virtual environment in Julia using an environment file? (for instance like [.yml file](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually) [for creating conda venv](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file))

Julia Version: `1.7.1`
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Julia virtual environment is defined via `Project.toml` file (that keeps package names and their acceptable versions) and `Manifest.toml` (that keeps the exact dependence tree and package versions generated along requirements defined in `Project.toml`).

Here is a sample Julia session:

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> pkg"generate MyProject"
 Generating  project MyProject:
    MyProject/Project.toml
    MyProject/src/MyProject.jl

julia> cd("MyProject")

julia> pkg"activate ."
 Activating environment at `/home/ubuntu/MyProject/Project.toml`
```

Finally, note that you can manipulate the `Project.toml` by eg. adding a package like this (this assumes the environment is active):

```
pkg"add DataFrames"
```

Sometimes you want to provide package version information to your `Project.toml`, for an example you could add at the end of the file:

```
[compat]
DataFrames = "1.3.0"
```

After adding the first dependency the `Mainifest.toml` file has been generated. Copying this file together with `Project.toml` across machines allows you to duplicate the environment.
In order to have all packages installed on a new machine you will need to run:

```
pkg"activate ."
pkg"instatiate"
```

`pkg"instatiate"` can also be used to generate `Mainfest.toml` when only the `Project.toml` is present.

The nice thing is that Julia can store many package versions simultaneously and the virtual environments only links to the central package repository (contrary to Python that copies several GBs of data each time).

Comment: and after appending `[compat]
DataFrames = "1.3.0" ` at the end of the `Project.toml`, how should I tell Julia to install what I recently mentioned in `Project.toml`?

Comment: `Pkg.add("PackageName")` or `pkg"add PackageName"` adds an approppiate entry to `Project.toml`

Comment: so this means we can't specify all preferred packages in `.toml` file and then command Julia to install all packages which we mentioned in `.toml` file. (Unlike what we can do in python with `.yml` files to create conda envs)

Comment: You can: `pkg"instatiate"` does exactly that. However env in Julia is defined in two files not one. One file is called `Project.toml` and the second file is called `Manifest.toml`. This functionality is a superset of functionality available in Python.

Answer (score 3):

pkg provides this with project.toml files.

Comment: Can you please provide an example [like this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#create-env-file-manually)?

Comment: https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/

Answer (score 3):

open julia in console

```
julia>]
Pkg> activate <Name>
<Name> Pkg> add <PackageName>
```

create directory with